# Using .NET (website project), how can I intercept all incoming image requests and alter their request path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, httphandler, global-asax

Thanks for looking.

## Background

I have inherited a very old (12 years) .NET *website* project what uses web form architecture.

This is a very large codebase and, when running on the web server, depends on a very large local resource folder of images. I am working remotely and have been told that the image folder will not be added to the source control; however, I can access it via a network folder (if connected to VPN).

If I hard-code any of the images to use the network path they work fine, but this is obviously not a good solution since there are thousands of images.

## Question

Is it possible to intercept any incoming request for an image file and, if the local image folder is not found (i.e. in development on my machine), use the network path URI instead to get the image? If so, what is the correct way to do this?

## What I have Tried

I tried intercepting the requests in the `Application_BeginRequest` method of the `global.asax` (which I was surprised to find in such an old project) but this does not intercept image requests apparently. My thinking was that I could re-structure the URL there and then comment that code out in production, but this also seems like it wouldn't be a great solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add handlers mappings for images extensions to Aspnet_isapi.dll in IIS config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's WebForms then you can most certainly use a HTTP Handler to achieve this.

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{        
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Handle your request here, using 
        // context.Request and System.IO 
        // to serve the image from network
    }
}
```

Then, you'll need to register & configure the Handler in Web.Config like so, for IIS6:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.jpg,*.png" type="Namespace.ImageHandler, AssemblyName" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Or IIS7:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="JpgImage" verb="*" path="*.jpg" type="Namespace.ImageHandler, AssemblyName" resourceType="File" />
        <add name="PngImage" verb="*" path="*.png" type="Namespace.ImageHandler, AssemblyName" resourceType="File" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I am going to give this a try and then report back. May take a few hours before I'm back.

Comment: Just remember because `ProcessRequest()` is intercepting and not returning anything, you'll need to use modify the output stream using `context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageBytes);`

Comment: thank you, but still having an issue. Seems that the application has an interceptor that is sending me straight to the default 404 page before the breakpoint in your recommended code is hit since the "images" folder isn't found locally. I am still getting to know this code base, so I will probably crack it in a few but if you have any advice, please let me know.

Comment: Interesting, are you registering the handlers correctly using your namespace and assembly names? I have this code above working in a blog application which simply re-routes favicon / apple-touch-icon requests at the root to a per-blog folder.